# Smallest sampling frequency to fully reconstruct a signal

Tags: sampling, homework, nyquist

Given the spectrum of analog signal $x_a(t)$ which is imaginary and band-limited, find the lowest sampling frequency to be able to reconstruct $x_a(t)$ from samples $x[n]$.

My attempt: Bandwidth of the signal is $\Delta \Omega = \Omega_2 - \Omega_1$
Such the sampling frequency should be $\Omega_T = 2\Delta \Omega$

Comment: I'd suggest drawing the spectrum of the sampled signal, just to make sure that there is no aliasing in the band of interest and that the proposed filter can indeed reconstruct the original signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is **not** correct for **complex** sampling:

For the specific case of a **complex bandpass** (analytic) signal whose spectrum is by definition zero for the negative frequencies such as:

$$ H(\Omega) =  \begin{cases}  0 &, \text{ by def. for } \Omega < 0 \\ A_\Omega &, \text{ nonzero for } \Omega_1 < \Omega < \Omega_2 \\ \end{cases}$$

then the necessary minimum sampling rate which would avoid **aliasing** (spectral overlap) is given by $$ \Omega_s > ( \Omega_2 - \Omega_1 ) $$ Note that if the signal were **real** with a symmetric bandwidth then the minimum sampling rate would be twice that of the complex case. Also then the allowed range of valid sampling rates would be found differently.

The **reconstrcution** filter that would yield the original **complex** signal $x(t)$ back will be a **complex bandpass filter**, not a real one. You can obtain the complex bandpass filter $H_+(\Omega)$ from the real bandpass filter $H_r(\Omega)$ using a Hilbert transformer such as:

$$ h_+(t) = h_r(t) + j \mathcal{H} \{h_r(t) \} $$

Note that for a given sampling rate you will be getting $F_s$ **complex** samples per second which is equivalent to $2 \times  F_s$ **real** samples per second. Hence the apparent advantage of complex sampling is actually not realized , as the total number of samples per second will be the same in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you have any links to something I can read about the spectrum of a complex bandpass signal?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Internet has links for everything: online classes, tutorials, books. Unfortunately, thus,  I haven't bookmarked one such. However you shall search for communication theory books for the utilization of complex bandpass (analytic) signals in modulation theory. Look for I/Q sampling as well. By the way, you can select the answer and/or upvote it, if you find it useful and/or correct. That's how the questions are closed when answered properly...

Comment: Thank you again, I'm looking at interesting information as we speak. One thing, if it is not too much, how would the ideal reconstruction filter look?
Would it be onesided from $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$ ?

Comment: @DSPson Yes the ideal reconstruction filter will be one sided bandpass. That's why I called it a **complex** filter. This way it will reject all other images including the one at the negative frequencies $-\Omega_2 < \Omega < -\Omega_1$ which would not be rejected by a **real** filter (whose spectrum is conjugate symmetric (has even magnitude) )...

Comment: @DSPson Thank you too. Please don't hesitate to come back for more questions, as you would encounter during your research...

Comment: @DSPson Of course I don't mind, but there are some rules here. And it's required to ask a new question if it's not directly related with the current one. The answer to your new question is about **downsampling** relation.

Comment: Hey, I have been thinking a lot about this issue, would the sampling frequency of only the bandwidth $\Omega_2 - \Omega_1$ suffice? since there is no symmetry in the negative spectrum (0 for all negative)?

Comment: @DSPson You are extremeley right !!! I should have somehow fooled the definitions of real and complex spectrum. Let me correct and restate it: *when the signal is complex and analytic then minimum sampling rate is $\Delta W$ complex samples per second, but when the signal is real with symmetric spectrum then the minimum sampling rate is $2 \Delta W$ real samples per second.* Note that the total number of samples in both cases are the same.

Comment: I found this on IQ sampling (http://www.cs.tut.fi/kurssit/TLT-5806/IQ.pdf)!
And got to thinking that the bandwidth must be enough to sample the complex signal. Thanks for the help :)